# How to implement push and pop functions in a stack when there are constant variables(compilation error)

Tags: c++, class, stack

I am making a class for a stack for an assignment but some variables have to be const. Apparently that's causing an error because when I have to make the push and pop functions because of the const variables. Any ideas on how to fix it? The error is: 
 `In member function 'void stack<T>::push(const T&) const':
error: increment of read-only location '((const stack<T>*)this)->stack<T>::top'`(same error for the pop function).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class stack{
public:
stack(int s){
  capacity = s;
  data = new T[capacity];
  top = 0;
}
stack(const stack &s){
  top=s.top;
  for(int j=1;j<=s.top;j++){
    data[j]=s.data[j];
  }
  capacity=s.capacity;
} ;
~stack(){
  delete []data;
} ;
const stack & operator = (const stack &s){
  delete []data;
  capacity=s.capacity;
  top=s.top;
  data= new T[capacity];
  for(int i=1;i<=s.top;i++){
    data[i]=s.data[i];
  }
}; 

bool empty() const {

  return top==0;
};
void push(const T &x) const{
 T y = *x;
  data[top++]=y;
};
T pop() const{

  return data[--top];
};
int size() const{
  return top;
};
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out,const stack& s){
  while(s.empty()!=1){
    out<<s.pop();
  }
    private:
 int capacity;
T *data;
int top;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove `const` from your declaration of `push` and `pop`.

```
void push(const T &x) {
```

not

```
void push(const T &x) const{
```

Keyword `const` on a method is for methods that **don't** change the object state. That's not true of `push` and `pop`, they do change the stack.

This is not the same as `const T& x`. The `x` object is not changed by being pushed onto the stack. So it can be declared `const`.

UPDATE

Another const error is here

```
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out,const stack& s){
    while(s.empty()!=1)
       out<<s.pop();
}
```

The `operator<<` should output a stack, it shouldn't change the stack (obviously). The stack `s` has been declared as `const` in `operator<<`, so that's good. But now look at what `operator<<` does. It calls `pop` **so it changes the stack**. That wrong in principle (because logically `operator<<` should not change the stack being output) and it's wrong in C++ because the stack `s` is declared const.

So rewrite `operator<<` so that it doesn't change the stack. Something more or less like this

```
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out,const stack& s) {
   for (int i = 0; i < s.top; ++i)
       out << s.data[i] << ' ';
   return out;
}
```

Comment: Then I get this error: "error: passing 'const stack<int>' as 'this' argument of 'T stack<T>::pop() [with T = int]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]" which is why I made them const in the first place.

Comment: Well don't declare your `stack` as const in the first place. A variable declared `const` cannot be changed. So you cannot push items onto a `const` stack (which is obvious if you think about it).

Comment: Don't just add `const` randomly, think about what the functions you've written do and whether they change things. Think about the variables you decalre and whether you will ever want them to change. If the answer is no declare them as const, otherwise don't.

Comment: My stack is not declared as const (the only stack that is const is the one use for the copy constructor. The items inserted into the stack are marked as const

Comment: @ellialvan You're going to have to post the code of that produces the error then. `error: passing 'const stack<int>'` certainly sounds like you've declared your stack as const.

Comment: also the top variable is not const, so I am having trouble figuring out why the error comes up

Comment: @ellialvan this isn't about the top variable, it's about the stack variable (in main presumably).

Comment: but in the constructor of the stack I have not made it const. I' a bit confused. But you're right I should probably post a separate question.

Comment: Please, look at the stack variable in **main**, how is that declared?

Comment: stack<int> s(10);

Comment: OK, well you are going to have to post the complete program. I can't help because I can't see the line of code that causes the error.

Comment: unfortunately I can't post another question for a few days. Is there any way that you can help me through some kind of chat? The deadline for the assignment is coming up in a few days.

Comment: @ellialvan see updated answer. You made a mistake in the way you implemented `operator<<`.

Comment: Oh you were right, I didn't notice that. However I still get an error:  In function 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const stack<T>&)':
 error: invalid use of non-static data member 'stack<T>::top' . same with data variable

Comment: @ellialvan _"I can't post another question for a few days."_ You can edit your question and provide a [mcve] showing the errors you get. That is required here anyways.

Comment: @ellialvan Yes my mistake, the code is fixed now. It should have been `s.top` and `s.data` not `top` and `data`. `s` is the stack you are trying to print.